# Trying to solve a stack error: library must match >=0.10, but the stack configuration has no specified version (latest applicable is 0.10)

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to use `brick` in a stack project.

Here's the error output:

> brick must match >=0.10, but the stack configuration has no specified version (latest applicable is 0.10)

It suggests:

> Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps in /my-project-path/stack.yaml:
>   - brick-0.10

Which I have done, but it doesn't help: same error message.

```
packages:
- '.'
# Dependency packages to be pulled from upstream that are not in the resolver
# (e.g., acme-missiles-0.3)
extra-deps: 
- brick-0.10
```

Then launching `stack solver` gives us:

> Using resolver: lts-7.1
>   Using compiler: ghc-8.0.1
>   Asking cabal to calculate a build plan...
>   Trying with packages from lts-7.1 as hard constraints...
>   Could not parse cabal-install errors:

```
>>>> Cabal errors begin
cabal: failed to parse output of 'ghc-pkg dump'
<<<< Cabal errors end
```

What is strange is that the `stack.yaml` was originally pointing to resolver `lts-6.2`, but `stack solver` used `lts-7.1` all the same.

My first two questions are:

- I'm wondering whether my `stack.yaml` file is read at all ?
- Is there something I can do to know what `ghc-pkg dump` failed exactly ?

And finally, do you know what could solve the issue ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the cabal executable is choking in this case. Try running stack build cabal-install to get the matching cabal executable for your snapshot.

If that fixes things, can you open a bug report?

Comment: Nice. I could launch `stack solver --update-config` afterwards. And now the project compile nicely.